# asp.net core how to delete existing image from a folder

Tags: image, asp.net-core

this is my function to update an instance but here i can't delete the old image it is only delete the instance from the database but the real image doesn't deleted from the image folder i have got this error message

The instance of entity type 'Images' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'ImageId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Edit( int id, [Bind("ImageId,Title,ImageFile")] Images images   )
    {

        if (id != images.ImageId)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var im = await _context.Images.FindAsync(id);
            //delete image from wwwroot/image
            var imagePath = Path.Combine(_hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "image", im.ImageName);
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(imagePath))
                System.IO.File.Delete(imagePath);

            //save image to wwwroot/image
            string wwwRootPath = _hostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(images.ImageFile.FileName);
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(images.ImageFile.FileName);
            images.ImageName = fileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;
            string path = Path.Combine(wwwRootPath + "/Image", fileName);
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await images.ImageFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }

            //Edit record

            try
            {
                _context.Update(images);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ImagesExists(images.ImageId))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(images);
    }
```

Comment: Which line of code were you expecting to delete the file? Did you look up how to delete a file in .NET? What did you find? What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the `ImageName` only then you should use your find method with`AsNoTracking()`. Probably you need to change your find method on something like that :

```
var im = await _context.Images.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id)
```

[About AsNoTracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbextensions.asnotracking?view=entity-framework-5.0.0)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you programmed your action to delete the old image... Deleting the image name from the database doesn't magically delete it from your wwwroot (assuming that's where the image is saved).

You can delete an image programmatically if you have its path like this:

```
System.IO.File.Delete(path_of_image);
```

But telling from your code, it doesn't look like you have the path of the image you want to delete. To get the path, I recommend doing either one of these two (if applicable):

- Adding another property in your view model for the old image path
- Querying the database for the old image path before updating the record

Comment: yeah you are right i have just edited my function now you can see the delete image part but the problem is that when i pressed the edit button i get this error message 

 The instance of entity type 'Images' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'ImageId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

Comment: @MohamedSamirSpot, That’s because EF Core can only track one entity at a time. So make your LINQ query await _context.Images.AsNoTracking().FindAsync(id)